# R: compare R squared of a linear model calculated with lm and the other method

Tags: r, regression, lm, linear

I am using a software in my analysis, from which I obtained the $R^2$ and estimated effects ($\beta$) of a linear regression model. In addition, it outputs the design matrix ($X$) of the model. To understand how $R^2$ was calculated in this software, I tried to calculate it in R with the design matrix and estimated effects.

Full model: y = cross + x

Reduced model: y = cross

The formula for calculating $R^2$ is 1-RSS_full/RSS_red, where RSS_full refers to the residual sum of squares of the full model and RSS_red is the residual sum of squares of the reduced model. I calculated the RSS_full with the residuals obtained from lm function in R. For RSS_red, I tried two methods to get the residuals and then RSS_red.

Method 1: apply lm function in R, which is sum(lm(y~cross-1,tol=1e-4)$residuals^2)

Method 2: firstly calculate the fitted value of the reduced model (y_red) with its design matrix and the estimated effects from the full model obtained from the software (y_red = cross%*%cross_effects), and then get the RSS_red by sum((y-y_red)^2).

The results of the two methods are different. However, the result of method 1 is the same as the one obtained from the Software. I do not know why they differ. Could someone give me some suggestions? Thank you! The design matrix, R codes and the output from the sotware are as follows.

Design matrix (ModelSJ file):

It can be downloaded from the dropbox share link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd3po8g8ixs2wod/ModelSJ?dl=0

R codes for calculating $R^2$:

```
data=as.matrix(read.table(file="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24381951/ModelSJ")) # reads the file from dropbox
y=data[,1] # the first column is the response/observed values.
x=data[,-1] # design matrix of the full model
cross=x[,10:12] # design matrix of the reduced model
RSS_full <- sum(lm(y~x-1,tol=1e-4)$residuals^2) # RSS of the full model

# Method 1
RSS_red <- sum(lm(y~cross-1,tol=1e-4)$residuals^2)
R2_1 <- 1-RSS_full/RSS_red 

# Method 2
cross_effects <- c(3.9171, 4.4411, 3.6381) # the estimated effects ß obtained 
#from the software based on the full model

y_red <- cross%*%cross_effects # fitted value
RSS_red <- sum((y-y_red)^2)
R2_2 <- 1-RSS_full/RSS_red

# Why are R2_1 and R2_2 not equal?
```

Output from the software:

it can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hp8p3kcf0d2nc5/testSJ_DON_iQTLm.xml?dl=0

Comment: If your dataset were accessible (for example, on github or dropbox), or if you used an inbuilt dataset, someone could reproduce the example, which would make it easier to see what was happening.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you for your advice. I added a dropbox share link for downloading the whole design Matrix.

Comment: I tweaked your code, so that R can pull the data straight from dropbox (I moved it to my account, I couldn't do it from your link).

Comment: I'm not sure where c(3.9171, 4.4411, 3.6381) come from. I thought cross_effects <-  coef(lm(y~cross-1,)) but that's not it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described, in plain English, as opposed to through R code, what two methods you are trying to use.  How can we validate what you've computed if we don't know what method you are trying to use to compute?

Comment: @StatsStudent Thank you for your suggestion. I described my question in plain English now.

Comment: @JeremyMiles thank you for your edit. c(3.9171, 4.4411, 3.6381) come from the output of the software I used for analysis. They are the effects of 'cross'. I also tried coef(lm(y~cross-1,)). I do not know why its result is different. By the way, I edited my question and uploaded the output.remy Miles

Comment: @JeremyMiles Is it because c(3.9171, 4.4411, 3.6381) were obtained based on the full model, but I used them for the calculation of the fitted value for reduced model?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. You say that those numbers were based on the full model, but when I run the model that you call full in the code, I get -106799  -106799  -106799    -1413 ... etc. You say that the result of method 1 is the same as you get from the software, but what are you doing to get that result. The formula you give for R2 is not the usual formula - that's the R2 change formula.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you for your answer. Actually, I do not understand how these numbers were calculated from the full model lm(y~cross-1,tol=1e-4)$coeff. The manual of the software said that there is restriction in solving the linear model, which is to make the sum of effects of the two levels of a factor equal to zero (this factor is specific to this biological study. It is called QTL, if you have interest). This may be different from the solution method in R. I think, maybe, this is the reason.

Comment: @JeremyMiles About the R2 formula, the usual formula is (SSR_full - SSR_reduced)/(SST - SSR_reduced), right? Isn't it equivalent to 1 - RSS_full/RSS_reduced? (SSR_full refers to sum of squares for regression with full model and SSR_reduced is that of reduced model. SST refers to the total sum of squares)

Comment: @JeremyMiles The reason I want to get that result is to understand how it was calculated and validate my method. Because in the later stage of analysis, I need to calculate R2 based on the design matrix and the estimated effects. (What I am doing is cross-validation. Briefly, a dataset is divided into two subset. One is used for estimating effects (Training set, TS). The other one is used for validating these effects (validation set, VS), by computing fitted value of VS based on these effects and (1) comparing them with observed values of VS (2) investigating R2.